# overlay gets cropped off in the landscape view

Tags: css, overlay

The overlay gets cropped off in the landscape view of mobile but its perfectly fine in the portrait view.

The code:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```

I want the overlay to scroll in the landscape view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;     
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code, now there appears a vertical scroll bar but it doesn't scroll .

Comment: Thanks @Varin. It worked. But what exactly is the difference between vh/vw and 100%.

Comment: vh/vw = view height/ view vidth. Those units will stretch element to the width/height of the current viewport. works well if you want a div to take the window height/width, for example a full height and full width banner.

100% will take 100% of the parent element.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.:)